# Схема Горнера вылетает с ошибкой

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно написать программу которая решала бы примеры с помощю схемы Горнера. У меня есть 2 EditText'а, после того, как ползователь ввел данные и нажал кнопку - данные переводяться в строку и т.д.(это в идеале). У меня же програма просто вылетает.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void show(View view){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Wait a sec", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        List<Integer> stepin = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //массив для степеней;
        List<Integer> chisla = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //массив для чисел;
        List<Character> x1 = new ArrayList<Character>(); //массив для символов "x";
        List<Character> symbols = new ArrayList<Character>(); //масив для символов "^";

        EditText polinomchik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.p);
        EditText monomchik = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.m);
        TextView resultV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.resultView);

        List<Character> polinom = new ArrayList<Character>(); //массив для полинома;
        List<Character> monom = new ArrayList<Character>(); //массив для монома;

        String p = polinomchik.getText().toString(); // строка с полиномом;
        String m = monomchik.getText().toString(); // строка с мономом;
        String v = ""; // строка с ответом;

        char [] pp = p.toCharArray();
        char [] mm = m.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i != polinomchik.length(); i++) // цикл для розформирования строки в ArrayList;
        {
            polinom.add(i, pp[i]);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i != monomchik.length(); i++) // цикл для розформирования строки в ArrayList;
        {
            monom.add(i, mm[i]);
        }

        int a = polinom.size(); //длинна массива;
        String charrik = "x^+-";
        char [] arr = charrik.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) // цикл для роспределения символов строки по массивам;
        {
            if (polinom.get(i).equals(arr[0])) {
                x1.add(polinom.get(i));
            } else if (polinom.get(i).equals(arr[1])) {
                symbols.add(polinom.get(i));
                stepin.add(Character.getNumericValue(polinom.get(i + 1)));
                i++;
            } else if (polinom.get(i).equals(arr[2])) {
                symbols.add(polinom.get(i));
            } else if (polinom.get(i).equals(arr[3])) {
                chisla.add(0 - Character.getNumericValue(polinom.get(i + 1)));
                symbols.add(polinom.get(i));
                i++;
            } else {
                chisla.add(Character.getNumericValue(polinom.get(i)));
            }

        }

        int[][] answer = new int[1][stepin.get(0) + 2]; // двумерный массив для созданий "таблицы";

        for (int i = 0; i < chisla.size(); i++) // цикл для заполнения 0-ой строки двумерного массива;
        {
            answer[0][i + 1] = chisla.get(i);
        }

        String cgn = Character.toString(monom.get(1)) + Character.toString(monom.get(2));
        int nnn = Integer.parseInt(cgn) * (-1);

        answer[1][0] = nnn; // заполнение 0-ого элемента 1-ой строки;
        answer[1][1] = chisla.get(0); // заполнение 1-ого элемента 1-ой строки;

        for (int i = 1; i < chisla.size(); i++) // цикл для заполнения вех элементов 1-ой строки;
        {
            answer[1][i + 1] = answer[1][0] * answer[1][i] + answer[0][i + 1];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < chisla.size() - 2; i++) // цикл для создания строки с ответом;
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < i; j++) {
                v = v + answer[1][j] + "x^" + stepin.get(j);
                if (answer[1][j + 1] > 0) {
                    v = v + "+" + answer[1][j + 1];
                }
            }
        }

        v = "(" + monom + ")" + "*" + "(" + v + answer[1][stepin.get(0) + 1] + ")" + "+" + answer[1][stepin.get(0) + 2];
        resultV.setText(v); // заменяю текс в TextView строкой с ответом;
    }
}
```

Логи:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ghost.gornersscheme, PID: 4825
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698)
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10908)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22557)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
at com.example.ghost.gornersscheme.MainActivity.Show(MainActivity.java:51)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5698) 
at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10908) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22557) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7231) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: Не понятно, в чём конкретно заключается ваша проблема. Из приведённой вами информации можно сказать лишь, что цикл пишется через "и".

Comment: Если вылетает, то наверняка с какой-то ошибкой. Суть ошибки подробно описывается в логах. Приведите их, пожалуйста.

Comment: Хотел спросить, можно ли перевести переменную типа String в массив или ArrayList?

Comment: В логах пишет что массивы пустые, потому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Не понятно, зачем вам public void Show. Методы, кстати, желательно называть с маленькой буквы. При запуске приложения автоматически выполняется метод onCreate, остальные, ваши собственные методы, вы вызываете уже из него. И перед названием ваших собственных методов не нужно писать public. Вы откуда-то вызываете метод Show? 

String в массив - вы имеете в виду String[] stringArray = new String[] {yourString}; ?

Comment: Show вызываю нажатием кнопки (в AndroidStudio). Я имею в виду можно ли из String s = "Привет", сделать String[] arr = new String[] {"П","р","и","в","е","т"}

Comment: String[] arr = s.split(""); или .split("(?!^)") 10 секунд поиска на этом же форуме.

Comment: Спасибо попробую

Comment: Запускал в режиме Debug, вылетает когда речь заходит о цикле для распределения символов строки по массивам;

Answer (score 0):

В цикле:

```
for (int i = 0; i != polinomchik.length(); i++) {
     monom.add(i, mm[i]);
}
```

Вы получаете `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, так как `polinomchik.length()` больше чем `mm.length`.

Например, если:

```
String polinomchik = "x^2+2x+1";
String monomchik = "x";
```

, то `polinomchik.length() == 8`, а `mm.length == 1`.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую исправить.